# Process Builder working with Tasks created from Enhanced Email will not work

Tags: process-builder, tasks, enhanced-emails

I am trying to update a custom Account field Last Sales Activity Date based off of the dates of completed Tasks of record type SalesTask (default for every profile except admin). For all Tasks this is working **except Email tasks created through Salesforce Inbox working in O365.**

A report of the Tasks created looks fine according to a report, but the field is not updating. Can't figure it out. (Note: Enhanced Email is turned on but don't know if this has anything to do with it.

**Evaluation Criteria:**

```
AND(
[Task].IsClosed = True, [Task].RecordType.Name = 'SalesTask',                    
[Task].ActivityDate <= TODAY(),
OR([Task].Account.Last_Sales_Activity_Date__c < 
   [Task].ActivityDate, ISBLANK([Task].Account.Last_Sales_Activity_Date__c ))
)
```

**Records which should trigger update to Last Sales Activity Date on Account:**

```
Task,Closed,Status,Company / Account,Subject,Activity Type,Task/Event Record Type,Date,Contact,Activity ID,Account ID
1,1,Completed,TEST ACCOUNT-update last activity date(s),Email: Testing #3,Email,SalesTask,6/19/2020,TEST CONTACT-update last activity,00T4Q000071poZE,0014Q00002ExWye
1,1,Completed,TEST ACCOUNT-update last activity date(s),Email: Test E-mail #3,Email,SalesTask,6/19/2020,TEST CONTACT-update last activity,00T4Q000071poBF,0014Q00002ExWye
1,1,Completed,TEST ACCOUNT-update last activity date(s),Email: Test E-mail,Email,SalesTask,6/19/2020,TEST CONTACT-update last activity,00T4Q000071pnRv,0014Q00002ExWye
1,1,Completed,TEST ACCOUNT-update last activity date(s),test future 1,In-Person Meeting,SalesTask,6 10 2020,TEST CONTACT-update last activity,00T4Q00006zeqXC,0014Q00002ExWye
```

**Current Value of Last Sales Activity Date on Account ID 0014Q00002ExWye = 6/10/2020**

Comment: so, when you look at the debug log for the running user that is using salesforce inbox, what do you see? - use [edit]

Comment: That's just it. I can't seem to get the logs dialed in to be able to isolate my test tasks. Too may "FLOW"-type statements in there for other stuff. Any coaching on that would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if doing in a sandbox, deactivate the irrelevant flows

Comment: Thanks. This is in production, not sandbox. There are no other active processes or flows on the Task object

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood the 'too many FLOW' type statements -- you need to find the FLOW debug statements that apply to evaluating the criteria so you can see the values on the Task as supplied by the O365 integration